# How can we remove curly brackets {} and double quotes "" from JSON type data in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm getting data from a server in JSON formate when I'm using the data in the html code with json pipe then it showing curly brackets and double quotes on the screen like -

Address: { "State": "Rajasthan", "City": "Jaipur" }

is there any way to remove the curly brackets and the double quotes.

html -

```
 <div class="card-text mb-1" *ngFor="let address of addresses | keyvalue">
      <p >Address: {{address.value | json | titlecase}}</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: it seems that the whole value of address itself is like {address:{"value":{"state":"rajasthan","city":"jaipur"}}}. If this is the case then you can access it by address. using Json directly will display data in json format. why don't you use HTML formatting with either by creating custom pipes or individually accessing the key value of json and then having it in the HTML like {{Address.State}}:{{Address.City}}

Comment: Just don’t use the json pipe..?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<div class="card-text mb-1" *ngFor="let address of addresses | keyvalue">
  <p >Address:
    <span *ngFor="let field of address.value | keyvalue; last as last">
      {{ field.value }}: {{ field.key }}<span *ngIf="!last">, </span>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

but it's better to do all this logic in the component and not in the template

```
const field = Object.values(this.addresses)
  .map((address) =>
    Object.entries(address).map(([key, value]) => `${key}: ${value}`)
  )
  .join(', ');
```